# How can i add background image as a Logo for my html heading

Tags: html, css

How can I add a background image for my heading(site name) ?

ps: I am only using html and css.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share the code you have already created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question heading is not enough? Please clarify more?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.wrapper {display:flex; flex-direction:row; align-items: center; font-size:40px;}
.wrapper span {margin:20px;}

.logo {height:100px; width:100px; background:url("https://picsum.photos/100/100");}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <span>My Website</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your description

```css
.head_back {
  background-image:url('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.s2014.png');
  padding:5px;
}

.heading {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="head_back">
  <h2 class="heading">My Website</h2>
</div>
```